# Why does float('Inf') is float('Inf') returns false in Python?

Tags: python, infinity

Whilst reading about Python's infinity, I came accross this :

```
>>>float('Inf') == float('Inf')
True
>>>float('Inf') is float('Inf')
False
>>>float('Inf') is not float('Inf')
True
```

I understand that equals works but I am wondering what `float('Inf')` actually points to that make the `is` test return `False` ? Is it different each time you call `float('Inf')` ?

EDIT: **I am not asking about the difference between `==` and `is`**. I am asking about the implementation details of `float('Inf')` and the nature of this object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`==\` and \`is\` in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: That is because `is` compares memory address of two objects, while `==` compares the objects themselves. || As above, while comparing by `is`, you actually create two different objects with same structure in memory. Two objects hold the same structure, but they are not the same, since addresses are different. Think it like universe.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what address does it point to ?

Comment: Evidently it makes a new `float` every time you call `float('Inf')`

Comment: Same reason `float('5.0') is float('5.0')` is false.

Comment: But `5.0 is 5.0` is `True`

Comment: @JacquesGaudin That's an implementation detail of your interpreter. It's not guaranteed to be true by the language.

Comment: @chepner: Interesting. Do you know where I should look in the source to get an idea of how this works ?

Comment: I thought it would be as `True` as `int(1.2) is int(1.4)`

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: [Here's the `float` constructor](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#l1811), which handles `float(thing)`, and [here's the bytecode compiler](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/compile.c), where the constant folding that causes `5.0 is 5.0` to be true happens. Remember that anything you read in these files is an implementation detail.

Comment: You can look in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c (code using `NSMALLPOSINTS` and `NSMALLNEGINTS`) to see how CPython preallocates integers between -5 and 257 and reuses them where possible. I don't think any such preallocation for floats exists, but it *could*.

Comment: @user2357112 and chepner: Thanks for understanding the bottom line of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` and `==` in python are quite different. `is` checks for identity while `==` checks for equality as some other users have already stated [here:Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

`float()` creates (or might create, depending on your interpreter) a new object which is not identical (but is equal) to another object created by `float()` having the same argument.

> Cpython may return a `True` for your check, but other VMs or
>   interpreters may not as described by [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/18/idiomatic-python-boolean-expressions/)

So:

```
 >>> float(2) is float(2)
 >>> False
 >>> float(2) == float(2)
 >>> True
```

In fact their identities can be seen as completely different using `id()`

```
 >>> id(float(2))
 >>> 251452
 >>> id(float(2)) # same call
 >>> 251934       # different result
```

So you should only use `is` if you really, **really** want to test for identity and not value.

Comment: `float()` *might* create a new object; an enterprising interpreter might memorize or preallocate certain values expected to be used commonly.

Comment: @chepner Which can readily be seen in python by doing something like `1000 is 1000` and seeing that it is true. However saying `x = 1000` and doing `x is 1000` is not true, for the very reason you just indicated.

Comment: @chepner I just indicated that in an edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `is` works on `objects`  and will only return TRUE if and if the 2 variables are pointing to same object , while `==` works on `value` so,, the reason it says `False` is because a new float is called up

Answer (score 0):

When you say `float('Inf')`, you're creating a new object on the fly that gets stored in memory somewhere and has a reference to that memory location. When you do

```
>>>float('Inf') == float('Inf')
```

You're creating two such objects, each with the same value, but in two different memory locations. The comparison here will compare the two values in these two memory locations and of course it will come out true.

When you do

```
>>>float('Inf') is float('Inf')
```

again you're creating two new objects each of the same value, but in different locations. But now you're trying to compare the references to the memory locations and of course those are not going to be the same.

This may be more clear if you consider the concept of

```
>>>a = float('Inf')
>>>b = float('Inf')
>>>a == b
True
>>>a is b
False
```

Hopefully, once you consider that `a` and `b` are the actual objects you're creating (rather than creating them with no name as in your examples) it is more clear what is happening.

Comment: Say "object" rather than "variable". There is some truth to the statement "Python doesn't have variables"; it has names that refer to objects.

Comment: That sounds like semantics to me. If you mean variable to be a primitive data type, then yes, python doesn't have variables. But I use variable in a general sense to mean a name that refers to something. In python that something is always an object, but the name is still a variable.

Comment: 'variable' suggests mutability though, in Python you can change what object a name refers to and you can mutate some objects, avoiding the word variable sometimes avoids confusion.

Comment: @zephyr Which is precisely why `float('Inf') == float('Inf')` does not create any variables; there are no names attached to the objects being created.

Answer (score 0):

And you don't need to invoke float() or 'Inf' to see this:

```
a = 1. 
b = 1. 
a == b 
True 
a is b 
False
```

Adding as answer only because I can't get formatting to work properly as a comment to @Nishant response.